# How to Encrypt Connection Strings in App.config VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection-string

I am trying to encrypt my app.config file for a windows desktop application.  I do not want to store the mysql connection string within the code because it can be reversed engineered which could be detremental to my DB.  Ive seen tutuorials for asp.net and c# but i cant seem to find how to do it using VB.net 2010 Express.  Any information is much appreciated, or other workarounds would be appreciated.

what i am trying to accomplish:  My application is going to connect to mysql database to check registration number when they register it.  If i do not encrypt the connection string it would be easy to add new key or drop table.  Thanks

Comment: No passwords (for external services) in your app. Never! Not SQL, not FTP, not EMail. Never ever!

Comment: So whats to stop them from reverse engineering your app to find out how you decrypt your password and then descrypting it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aspnet_regiis.exe tool, as long as you rename, temporarily, your `app.config` to `web.config`, like this:

```
rename App.config web.config
aspnet_regiis -pef NameOfSectionYouWantToEncryptHere . -prov DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
rename web.config App.config
```

Read [Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.